# Using Logstash to delete an index from ES

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to delete an index from `ES` before uploading a updated version of the data from `MySQL`. As of today I use curl to delete the data and Logstash to upload, however I was wondering if there is a way where I do not have to do it manually separated, best case being able to use Logstash (with its scheduler) to have it fully automatic. Say is there a way to simply write something in my config-file to do this?

How I´m deleting today :

```
curl -X -DELETE 'http://localhost:9200/index'
```

The reason to why I am deleting the index before uploading new data is because I am  uploading data that is coming from various sources, hence the ability to decide when the data was updated is not that easy. This is why I have chosen to delete the data before uploading a updated version. If there is a smarter way to approach this problem I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You can create a batch file that runs the logstash process and curator actions together.*

Download and [install curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/installation.html) using the instructions. Use [curator command line](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/command-line.html) to perform actions on indices. For deletion, check out [Delete Indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/delete_indices.html) action.

```
action: delete_indices
description: >-
  Delete indices older than 45 days (based on index name), for logstash-
  prefixed indices. Ignore the error if the filter does not result in an
  actionable list of indices (ignore_empty_list) and exit cleanly.
options:
  ignore_empty_list: True
  disable_action: True
filters:
- filtertype: pattern
  kind: prefix
  value: %{Index_Name}
- filtertype: age
  source: name
  direction: older
  timestring: '%Y.%m.%d'
  unit: days
  unit_count: 45
```

[Source - Delete Indices Example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/ex_delete_indices.html#ex_delete_indices)